# How to do a SQL Server select using a timestamp minus a certain number of hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

Right now I have a SQL query that allows me to select entries in a table that have been inserted over the past day.

The query is:

```
Select account from mytable where create_date > current_timestamp - 1
```

But suppose that I wanted to select entries that had been inserted over the base two hours?

How would I write that query?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), like so:

```
SELECT account
FROM MyTable
WHERE create_date > DATEADD(hh, -2, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that a timestamp and a datetime are extremely different in sql server. A timestamp is a unique binary number whereas a datetime is a date and time combination. I think you'll need datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You could try along the lines of

```
Select account from mytable where create_date > current_timestamp - 0.083333333
```